# Can Twitter be used as "Support URL" in iTunes Connect of iOS

Tags: twitter, app-store-connect

Excuse me, in iTunes Connect Developer Guide (of iOS), I see that "Support URL" is required. I searched on web then know that Facebook is OK. But can Twitter also be used as this "Support URL"? Does anybody know this for sure?https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Appendices/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH26-SW2

Answer (score 13):

Yes, that shouldn't be a problem. According to Apple's documentation:

> The support URL must lead to actual contact information so that your users can contact you regarding app issues, general feedback, and feature enhancement requests.

If your Twitter page is where you communicate with your users and where it is most convenient for them to contact you, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will try.O(∩_∩)O~

Comment: @ViolaTangjing did it work? i have the same problem. Curious to know if i can submit as suggested in the answer

Comment: @ViolaTangjing I'd like to have this confirmed too.

Comment: @prabhu I recently submitted an app for review with my twitter page as support page. It got approved.

Comment: @Isuru I can confirm it, my twitter page got approved as support page.

Comment: @DoubleM Thanks. I got mine approved too.